# Is the theory of real closed fields expanded by restricted analytic functions decidable?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Is the theory of real closed fields expanded by restricted analytic functions decidable?  I have been doing a lot of reading on the subject, but I can't quite find a straight answer on this one.  The theory seems to enjoy many good properties, o-minimality, completeness, quantifier elimination.  But I can't seem to find anything about it being decidable or undecidable.  I think it needs to be recursively axiomatized in order for it to be decidable, but I am not quite sure.  Does that mean that real closed fields augmented with a specified list of restricted analytic functions is decidable?

Comment: Isn't the language uncountable here? If so than you can't encode formulas by numbers, so there is no notion of decidability.

Comment: Concerning the recursive axiomatisability: there is no intrinsic reason why you can't take a non-recursive axiomatisation of a theory and somehow use it to prove that the theory is decidable. However, if you did that, you would have that the theory is recursively axiomatisable as an immediate corollary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Levon Haykazyan pointed out in a comment, since there are uncountably many analytic functions, the language is uncountable. In order to discuss whether a theory is decidable, the appropriate definitions require that the language in question be presented *computably*: that is, the function and relation symbols are given by natural numbers, and the arity function (telling how many arguments a symbol takes) must be a computable function. Since this presentation requires us to associate symbols with natural numbers, it doesn't make sense for uncountable languages.